# Android: Alert Dialog disappears and executes next Intent

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm using a GPS disabled AlertDialog and once the user enables GPS, I move onto another Activity via an Intent. The problem is that the AlertDialog appears and then moves onto the next activity before I can click on any button on the Dialog.
What do i need to do so that the next Intent executes only once I have performed the action on the AlertDialog?
Here is my code:

```
public void OnClickNearMe(View view) {
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        createGpsDisabledAlert();
    }
    Location locationResult = null;
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    boolean locationEnabled = myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

    if (locationEnabled == true) {
        locationResult = myLocation.getLocationResult();
        showResultsScreen(locationResult);
    } else
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noLoc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return;
}

private void createGpsDisabledAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS is disabled! Would you like to enable it?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            showGpsOptions();
                        }
                    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Do nothing",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

private void showGpsOptions() {
    Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(
            android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
}

private void showResultsScreen(Location locationResult) {
    Intent resultsIntent = new Intent(this, ResultScreenList.class);
    startActivity(resultsIntent);
}
```

Thanks in advance for all your answers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you show the dialog, `createGpsDisabledAlert` will continue on and finish even before you click OK or Cancel. Maybe refactor the rest of the code in `OnClickNearMe` to another method and call it only if location isn't enabled, and also call it after your settings page. Maybe something like:

```
public void OnClickNearMe(View view) {
    LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){   
        createGpsDisabledAlert();   
    } else {
        getLocation();
    }
}

private void getLocation() {
    Location locationResult = null;
    MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
    boolean locationEnabled = myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);

    if (locationEnabled == true) {
        locationResult = myLocation.getLocationResult();
        showResultsScreen(locationResult);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.noLoc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void createGpsDisabledAlert(){   
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);   
    builder.setMessage("Your GPS is disabled! Would you like to enable it?")   
         .setCancelable(false)   
        .setPositiveButton("Enable GPS",   
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){   
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                   showGpsOptions(); 
                   getLocation();
              }   
         });   
         builder.setNegativeButton("Do nothing",   
              new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){   
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){   
                   dialog.cancel(); 
              }   
         });   
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
    }  

    private void showGpsOptions(){   
            Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(   
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);   
           startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);   
    }  

    private void showResultsScreen(Location locationResult){
         Intent resultsIntent = new Intent(this, ResultScreenList.class); 
           startActivity(resultsIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Is there some way i can direct the user out of the settings page instead of having to press the back button? This was my original intention.

Comment: Nothing too obvious comes to mind. You could maybe pop up a toast to direct the user to press back after they're done, but besides that I don't have any bright ideas on that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that while the GPS location isn't enabled, you are still getting a location in myLocation.getLocation.

After you call createGpsDisabledAlert(), you probably should return instead of continuing with the method.